# Sync folder between Mac and Windows Server

Tags: windows, macos, mac, sync, smb

I've got a Small Business Server at work and a MacBook on the go. I want to sync a folder from the server on my MacBook so I can work on the files locally.

I'm looking for a solution that syncs my MacBook and the server when I connect to the company network. Both sides may change, so it should handle conflicts (that is: not just copy over the newest file, also tell me when *both* have changed. Diff'ing is not necessary).

I thought this would surely be possible, but I haven't found any nice apps to handle this. Any ideas? Would DropBox be able to do this?

Notes:

- I want to rule out the command line (I'm asking this question for somebody with no CLI experience)
- I cannot run apps on the server, only on the macbook.
- I'm not interested in mail or calendars, just files and folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need DropBox installed on the server, yes. I tend to think of DropBox as a good way to share files between two or more of your own computers, and share some folders with friends. That is, not a client-server sync tool. For that, I use [Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/). There are many products like this (search Pure-Mac) but I've only had experience with Synkron and it works very well for my needs.

You can set it up to automatically grab the newest version from either side of the synchronization. Then, if there are any conflicts, it will alert you and you will be able to choose which of the two files you want to keep. This conflict resolution dialog box also contains information on which of the two files is newer.

All in all, a great program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Running Dropbox on the server is not an option, but I'll look into Synkron.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... maybe [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) would work. However, from the page description it doesn't mention if both machines need the software installed, only that you don't require special priviledges to install and use it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, DropBox is able to

Comment: Won't that require dropbox to run on the server?